# Proper use of CodeContract Requires

Tags: .net, c#-4.0, code-contracts

Basically I want to know if using a code contract to determine if a key exists in a ConcurrentDictionary is an acceptable use of a code contract. It doesn't feel right to me because it's more than parameter check as it depends on the state of the dictionary at runtime.

```
public class MyClass
{
    private ConcurrentDictionary<string, object> someItems = 
        new ConcurrentDictionary<string, object>();

    public object GetItem(string itemName)
    {
        Contract.Requires<ArgumentNullException>(!String.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(itemName));

        // ?? Is this a correct alternative to checking for null???
        Contract.Requires<KeyNotFoundException>(someItems.ContainsKey(itemName));

        return someItems[itemName];
    }
}
```

But if it is okay, it's a cleaner method that has 2 Contract.Requires and one return, over the traditional way below.

```
public class MyClass
{
    private ConcurrentDictionary<string, object> someItems = 
        new ConcurrentDictionary<string, object>();

    public object GetItem(string itemName)
    {
        Contract.Requires<ArgumentNullException>(!String.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(itemName));

        // Traditional null check
        var item = someItems[itemName];

        if (item == null)
        {
            throw new KeyNotFoundException("Item " + itemName + " not found.");
        }

        return item;            
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looks a bit odd to me: the internal state of the class (i.e. the contents of `someItems` dictionary) is definitely **not** a part of a contract. You *can* use it this way, but contract checks are supposed to let the caller know what exactly was wrong. In this case a caller will never guess which arguments are allowed and which are not - even after getting `KeyNotFoundException`.

Moreover, in this particular case throwing an exception if object is not found in dictionary does not look consistent, in my opinion it would make more sense to return `null`.

By the way, in your first example `itemName` is searched twice in the dictionary.

Comment: KeyNotFoundException on a method GetItem with one argument pretty much tells me what exactly was wrong; however, I tend to have the same feeling about this particular test not being a contract per se. Throwing vs. returning null is a design consideration for the API, not really a code contract concern. Overall I think you've validated my same concern with nice points. Thanks!